# MVC 5 Enviar Correo al insertar con System.Net.Mail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Necesito enviar una notificaciones cada vez que el usuario inserta un nuevo objeto en la base de datos .

por ejemplo en mi controlador 
al insertar el objeto posterior al savechanges envie el correo 
 db.Altas.Add(alta);
                db.SaveChanges();

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando `Entity Framework` una vez que se inserta a la base de datos el modelo que deseas, te llena el campo de tu `Primary Key`

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
  db.Altas.Add(alta);
  db.SaveChanges();

  if(alta.Id > 0)
  {
     //Logica para enviar correo
  }

}
```

//Envio de correo

```
var message = new MailMessage
{
   Subject = "Asunto",
   Body = "Mensaje/Cuerpo",
   IsBodyHtml = true
};

message.From = new MailAddress("noreply@noreply.com", "Mi Aplicacion");
message.To.Add("correousuario@correo");


 var client = new SmtpClient
 {
   EnableSsl = true//Si es SSL
 };

client.Send(message);
message.Dispose();
client.Dispose();
```

Edit:

WebConfig para las credenciales

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="noreply@noreply.com">
        <network enableSsl="true" host="mail.dominio.com" port="25" userName="noreply" password="noreply" defaultCredentials="false" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: En la  linea "Noreply " debo colocar mi correo ?           y el add puedo utlizar la variable donde digito el correo ?                   
   message.From = new MailAddress("noreply@noreply.com", "Mi Aplicacion");
message.To.Add(alta.correo);

Comment: Si, en noreply va el correo de donde vas a mandar el correo.
En el add a que destinatario, puedes poner varios add

Comment: Agregue un edit para el webconfig. hay que activar o desactivar SSL dependiendo y el puerto modificarlo al que debe de ser en tu servidor de correos

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio excelente ,solo configure el web config distinto . Una pregunta adicional y para enviar un correo de aviso cuando un usuario edita ??         y en el body del correo como puedo realizar carga imagen?

Comment: Una vez que actualizes, tu db.SaveChanges te regresa un entero, si es 0 es que no se actualizo, sin embargo si no te actualize lo mas seguro es que encuentres una excepcion por lo cual una vez que se ejecute correctamente el savechanges quiere decir que se actualizo.

En cuando a la imagen en el cuerpo.
Debes de tener activada la opcion de IsBodyHtml=true, y en el body mandar tu elemento de html <img src='url'/>

Comment: Gracias excelentes respuestas las 3 me funcionaron

Comment: una consulta como puedo agregarle estilos con boostrap a la tabla , he intentado pero al colocar css pone razor como texto .